# Weighted mean of a column in csv file in Java

Tags: java, csv

I am trying to compute the number of elements in a column present in a CSV file using which I would like to compute the mean.

This is how I tried to find the length of the column, but it gives me the length of each data in the column. It's something very silly but I have been stuck with this for a long time.

```html
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                String splitBy = ";";
                int x;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("bank.csv"));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) !=null) {
             String[] b = line.split(splitBy);
             x = b[10].length();
             System.out.println("length " + x);
        }
        br.close();

  }
```

This is the CSV file:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pandutruhandito/practice_bank_marketing_data/master/bank/bank-full.csv

Comment: Can you show a portion of your csv file?

Comment: Don't you like need to count the lines in your csv to get your total number of values?

Comment: I have added the link to the csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want something like the following. A few notes.

- If a value is always required then you can simply count the number of lines in the CSV to give you the number of values in the column. Otherwise you'll need to check if there is an actual value.
- You were grabbing the month column, remember indexes start at 0.

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      final String splitBy = ";";
      int totalValue = 0;
      int columnCount = 0;
      final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/test/bank-full.csv"));
      String line;
      // Throw away headers.
      line = br.readLine();
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
      {
           String[] splitCSV = line.split(splitBy);
           if (!splitCSV[9].equals(""))
           {
               totalValue += Integer.parseInt(splitCSV[9]);
               columnCount++;
           }
      }
      br.close();
      System.out.println("Average is " + totalValue / columnCount);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

b[10].length() is incorrect: it gives you the size of string of the 10th element in a particular line (and it changes in the loop)

line.length(): lengh of the line

b.length: number of elements in a line

if you want the number of columns, you can just only keep the number of lines read (just count your readlin())

Or you can also keep everything in a table.

beware: some csv have , or ; , and perhaps inside " (if there is string)

Comment: b[10] corresponds to a column. I want how many elements are there in that column.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `x = b.length;` which will give you exact length per line.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String splitBy = ";";
    int x;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("bank.csv"));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) !=null) {
        String[] b = line.split(splitBy);
        x = b.length;
        System.out.println("length " + x);
    }
    br.close();
}
```